# vue.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')

Tags: vue.js

Hello I am using laravel to bulid app and now I am using vue.js as well but quite new to it.

Recently, I got this bug

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'component')
```

and the button is showing on the page also it ruined my boostrap, I have been googling for hours still can't solve it.

My app.js file

```
require("./bootstrap");

window.Vue = require("vue").default;
Vue.component(
"Follow-Button",
require("./components/FollowButton.vue").default
);



const app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
 });
```

My vue

```
<template>
 <div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-4 w-100 mt-2" @click="followUser">
        追蹤
    </button>
 </div>
</template>
<script>
 export default {
   mounted() {
      console.log("Component mounted.");
   },
   method: {
      followUser: function () {
          alert("hey");
       },
   },
  } ;
 </script>
```

My index.blade.php(it's too long I just cut this it's in app of course)

```
 <Follow-Button></Follow-Button>
```